# Programmatically Set JQuery Mobile slider value

Tags: jquery-mobile

How do I programmatically set the value of a slider in JQuery mobile? I have the following slider defined:

```
<label for="optionSlider">Are you sure?</label>
<select id="optionSlider" name="slider" data-role="slider">
  <option value="no">No</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

When the page is shown, I want to set it to "yes". I know that I can use the "selected" attribute, but because the value will be dynamic,I need to figure out how to set it programmatically. Currently, I'm using the following:

```
$("#myPage").live("pageshow", function () {
  var flag = "yes"
  if ((flag != null) && (flag != undefined)) {
    if (isTrackSet == "no") {
      $("#optionSlider", "#myPage").val("no");
    } else {
      $("#optionSlider", "#myPage").val("yes");
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call a refresh on your slider:

```
.slider("refresh");
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-slider.html

Comment: Even though this is what the docs say, I haven't been able to get this to work.

Comment: Post a question and I will gladly help.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
   <select name="slider" id="stopplay" data-role="slider">
     <option value="off">Play</option>
     <option value="on" >Stop</option>
   </select>

$("#stopplay").val('on').slider("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different approaches and always ended up getting this error:

> cannot-call-methods-on-slider-prior-to-initialization

Finally I found this approach to work:

```
  $('#member').page(); //the id of the page where the slider resides
  $('#slider').val(listsize); // setting the value from a localstorage item
  $('#slider').slider('refresh');
```